# ⋇ "Division Times" operator in Unicode (U+22C7)?

Tags: notation, arithmetic, binary-operations

I found this maths operator in Unicode:

⋇

It is called "Division Times" (U+22C7).

Does it behave like ±? For example: 3 ± 2 means it is an ∈ {1, 5}. So 3 ⋇ 2 means it is an ∈ {1.5, 6}?

Comment: First time i hear of this "operator". Not a standard one. I wonder why this made into Unicode...

Comment: Idly I wonder if there is a LaTeX command for this.

Comment: @quid: Detexify doesn't seem to know it.

Comment: It's been in Unicode since the first version of the Unicode Character Database (version 1.1.5, July 1995). Digging up a rationale for it may be difficult.

Comment: Why edit my my element of symbols into "is an element of"?

Comment: Your  = ∈ is not a well-formed expression. It does not mean anything.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks for that  information. [I asked it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319666/is-there-a-command-to-typeset-the-unicode-symbol-division-times-u22c7) on [tex.se]

Comment: "is equal to a member of" using symbols instead of words seemed reasonable. I have changed it back to something similar to your edit @quid

Comment: The version with just $\in$ is alright. I feel it is slightly less precise than the earlier version, but then I am biased. :-) I understood that was what you meant but one must not use = in that way.

Comment: Unicode characters do not "behave". Your semantic interpretation of them "behaves".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The intent  ought to be what you said. So, it is  $a ⋇ b$ is short for "$a \ b$ or $a \ b^{-1}$" that is the multiplicative analogue of $\pm$.

Yet, a more common way to write $a ⋇ b$ is just $a \  b^{\pm 1}$.

In addition, I never heard of this operator, all the early search hits are for Unicode-tables not math, and at least to me it looks quite similar to an asterisks at small font size.

In short, it seems more like an artifact of getting a symbol-set somehow 'complete.' Rather than something that is actually used.

That said, [I just learned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319666/is-there-a-command-to-typeset-the-unicode-symbol-division-times-u22c7) that there is a LaTeX (needs amssymb) and also MatjJax command for it,  it is `\divideontimes` giving $\divideontimes$

Comment: This answer won, but both answers are good and appreciated. I wish there was a feature to combine similar answers into one answer.

Comment: Coincidentally, I saw it appear yesterday in Go Yamashita's notes on inter-universal Teichmüller theory, and while I'm not sure, I imagine it didn't mean anything like what you said.

Comment: @MJD that's amazing. I just checked some of the slides. I actually think it is used roughly with about those semantics though. Well, it is not even used as a binary operator, but rather as a superscript. Yet it does appear to indicate that elements and their multiplicative inverses are identified.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't behave like $\pm$. An important part of how $\pm$ behaves is that *it is likely to be understood without further explanation*, and the $⋇$ sign does not have that property.

You can use it for "divided or multiplied by" if you want, but you will have to explain this usage to your reader before you do so, because you can't expect it to be clear that is what you want.

I would expect it is most likely to be used when someone needs a symbol for a new thing that behaves syntactically like a multiplication-like operator but is not actual multiplication -- and there is reason not to use the more common choices such as $*$, $\star$, $\otimes$, $\circledast$, and so forth.

Comment: Downvoted because the lede here is simply neither tenable nor persuasive. I introduce a legion of community college students to the plus-or-minus every semester, and the majority are uniformly confused, baffled, and desperate for an explanation. Just like any notation someone hasn't seen before.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Sure, but any paper using ± can rely on much of its audience being part of the legions of students that have been introduced to it. Sure, everything has to be introduced _some_ time - you had to learn + and − themselves in primary school, after all. But ⋇ is never introduced to any general population of students at all.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, how did people get to a college without having seen the quadratic formula? Even the Wikipedia entry on it mentions the ± symbol.

Comment: @QuirinF.Schroll: That level of math (Algebra II) isn't required to graduate a U.S. high school. It's not even required to graduate from college (U.S. 2-year degree).

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, really? You sure, we talk about the same thing, the solutions for x² + a x + b = 0? That’s baffling.

Comment: @QuirinF.Schroll: Indeed.

Comment: As an example I'll cite the CUNY Elementary Algebra Final Exam, which was previously a base-level requirement to graduate with a CUNY 2-year college degree. Note the quadratic formula isn't required in that curriculum (e.g., see question #17). I say _was_ because even this level of algebra requirement was removed as of last year. https://www.cuny.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/page-assets/academics/testing/Sample-CEAFE-D-1.pdf

Comment: ... and to relate directly to this question, note that the $\pm$ symbol appears no place in that final exam.