# Why don't we see a $\frac{\times}{ \div}$ like we see $\pm$?

Tags: notation

It's common to see a plus-minus ($\pm$), for example in describing error
$$
t=72 \pm 3
$$
or in the quadratic formula 
$$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
or identities like
$$
\sin(A \pm B) = \sin(A) \cos(B) \pm \cos(A) \sin(B)
$$

I've never seen an analogous version combining multiplication with division, something like $\frac{\times}{\div}$

> Does this ever come up, and if not why?

I suspect it simply isn't as naturally useful as $\pm$.

Comment: I've had to use it before (and used the obvious stacked symbol) but I haven't seen it used much either -- actually I'm not sure if I've seen it at all.

Comment: Could it be because $\pm$ are implicitly unary (only have one operand) whereas $\times$ and $\div$ require two operators.

Comment: @gowrath thats not true, $+$ and $-$ are also binary operators...

Comment: Related: ["Q: What is the symbol ''⋇
'' (DIVIDE TIMES) for?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954186/what-is-the-symbol-divideontimes-divide-times-for?s=1|1.0008). (I seem to recall that there was another similar question within the past few weeks, but I can't find it.)

Comment: @Blue Nice!  I had searched for something just like that but apparently wasn't searching the right words.

Comment: [What is the symbol ''⋇
'' (DIVIDE TIMES) for?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954186/what-is-the-symbol-divideontimes-divide-times-for)  | [⋇ “Division Times” operator in Unicode (U+22C7)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861245/⋇-division-times-operator-in-unicode-u22c7)

Comment: @gowrath I disagree that $\pm a$ means $1+a$ and $1-a$. Why would a 1 be implied?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps because 
$$
a\frac{\times}{\div}b
$$
(typographically quite horrible) is written as
$$
a\cdot b^{\pm1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated,  square root can be + or -.
$\pm$ shows this ambiguity.

As far as I know,
there is no similar use case
where the choice is
to multiply or divide
by an expression.

Comment: One example is $\log(a\cdot b) = \log(a)+\log(b)$ and $\log(a\div b) = \log(a)-\log(b)$. I've never seen it combined, but it could be.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this question is primarily opinion-based, so here is my opinion:

- The expression $[t=72\pm3]$ is equivalent to $[t=72+(+3)]\vee[t=72+(-3)]$
- The expression $[t=72\frac{\times}{\div}3]$ would be equivalent to $[t=72\times3]\vee[t=72\times\frac13]$

So the second operand "looks the same" in the case of $\pm$ but not in the case of $\frac{\times}{\div}$.

If we had a different notation for $\frac13$ (for example, $\color\red3$), then it might have seemed more appropriate to denote something like $[t=72\frac{\times}{\div}3]$, which would be equivalent to $[t=72\times3]\vee[t=72\times\color\red3]$.

So it's basically a matter of "backward compatibility" with our existing notation for *inverse*...

Comment: 72 / 3 is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are many function (square roots for ex.) where $f(x) = f(-x)$ and for $f^{-1}$, the $\pm$ is useful. If there were common functions where $f(x) = f(\frac{1}{x})$ it might be a thing. Can anyone think of example functions like this?

Comment: One example is $f(x)  = x^0$

Comment: $f(x)=(\log x)^2$ is another

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication sign $\cdot$ is usually omited in abelian groups (or even non-abelian). I think the most important thing is, that something like $\div$ does mislead the reader, because if we consider $a\div b$, then $b$ is not on the same level as $a$, but in contrary the sumbology does suggest so. This can cause serious errors in calculations whereas $\frac{a}{b}$ is much more clearer as well as $ab^{-1}$. I think this levelness is the main point of never using $\div$.